# Azure blob deletion using @azure/storage-blob and nodejs

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I wish to delete blobs along with their snapshots. what is the argument or condition to be passed to include snapshot deletion. Here's my code below :

```
const blobServiceClient = require("./getCred");

async function deleteRecord() {
  try {
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient("containerName");
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient("dummy.json");
    const deleteBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.deleteIfExists();
    console.log(`Deleted  successfully ${deleteBlobResponse.requestId}`);
    return `Deleted  successfully ${deleteBlobResponse.requestId}`;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return err;
  }
}

deleteRecord();
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the **DeleteSnapshotsOptionType** in `deleteIfExists()` your code. Please follow the workaround below

```
blockBlobClient.deleteIfExists(DeleteSnapshotsOptionType.INCLUDE);
```

In a [**delete(BlobDeleteOptions)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-blockblobclient-delete) & [**deleteIfExists(BlobDeleteOptions)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-blockblobclient-deleteifexists) consist of below option types which can help to filter the delete operation

The option properties are
[abortSignal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobdeleteoptions?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-blobdeleteoptions-abortsignal) , [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobdeleteoptions?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-blobdeleteoptions-conditions) , [customerProvidedKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobdeleteoptions?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-blobdeleteoptions-customerprovidedkey) , [deleteSnapshots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobdeleteoptions?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-blobdeleteoptions-deletesnapshots), and [tracingOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobdeleteoptions?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-blobdeleteoptions-tracingoptions)

In `DeleteSnapshots` we have 2 options

1. **include**: Delete the base blob and all of its snapshots.
2. **only**: Delete only the blob's snapshots and not the blob itself.

After changing the `blockBlobClient.deleteIfExists(DeleteSnapshotsOptionType.INCLUDE);` It able to delete the blob along with snapshots.

Changed source code:

```
const blobServiceClient = require("./getCred");
async function deleteRecord() {
    try {
        const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient("containerName");
        const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient("dummy.json");
        const deleteBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.deleteIfExists( DeleteSnapshotsOptionType.INCLUDE);
        console.log(`Deleted  successfully ${deleteBlobResponse.requestId}`);
        return `Deleted  successfully ${deleteBlobResponse.requestId}`;
    
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }
}

deleteRecord();
```